# console.log no output on Mac works on MacBook

Tags: javascript, macos, console.log

I have an HTML file with some javascript (I am doing a course on web development). In the javascript I have a line "console.log(event)". After opening the file in Chrome and  going to Inspect - Console on my iMac, there is no output in the console. When I do exactly the same on my MacBook, I get the expected output in the console (see screenshot). I have done the following steps to try to fix this:
- searched the internet for solutions
- looked at different settings in Chrome on iMac and MacBook
- restarted Chrome on iMac
- restarted iMac
- uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome on iMac
- tried different programs e.g. from w3schools.com with the same result: not working on iMac but works fine on MacBook
Could you please help to resolve this issue.
Regards,
Kees

[image: console output on Mac and MacBook]

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the input field for filter. In imac it is filtering contents that has string `color`